# Is partial trace additive in sense of direct sum?

Tags: functional-analysis, quantum-information

I have an intuition, but not sure exactly, whether the partial trace is additive in the sense of direct sum. My intuition is that partial trace is additive and direct sum acts as a sum but with orthogonality (I hope I understand that right).

I mean: $Tr_{E_1} V_1 \oplus Tr_{E_2}V_2 = Tr_{E_1 \oplus E_2} (V_1 \oplus V_2) $.

Actually this kind of means that $(E_1 \otimes B_2) \oplus (E_2 \otimes B_2) = (E_1 \oplus E_2)\otimes(B_1\oplus B_2)$. Which I am not sure, but might be legit.

Is that true? Assuming $V_i: B_i \otimes E_i \longrightarrow B_i \otimes E_i$.

Comment: Is $V_1\oplus V_2 = (V_1,V_2)$ ?

Comment: @LL3.14 That notation doesn't make much sense as written, but it is true in this context that $(V_1 \oplus V_2)(x_1,x_2) = (V_1(x_1), V_2(x_2))$

Comment: Usually it is $(V_1\otimes V_2)(x_1,x_2) = V_1(x_1)V_2(x_2)$ while while $E_1⊕ E_2$ is the set of elements of the form $(V_1,V_2)$, so I do not get what is $V_1(x_1)⊕ V_2(x_2)$.

Comment: Oh ok, clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B_1 = B_2 = B$, then it is true in a sense, but you have to be careful about what you mean by $\operatorname{Tr}_{E_1 \oplus E_2}$. In particular, we note that the spaces
$$
(E_1 \otimes B) \oplus (E_2 \otimes B), \quad (E_1 \oplus E_2) \otimes B
$$
are canonically isomorphic. In particular, the linear map $\Phi: (E_1 \oplus E_2) \otimes B \to$ $(E_1 \otimes B) \oplus (E_2 \otimes B)$ defined such that
$
\Phi[(x_1 \oplus x_2) \otimes y] = (x_1 \otimes y) \oplus (x_2 \otimes y)
$
defines an isomorphism.

With that said, your statement can be rendered as
$$
\operatorname{tr}_{E_1 \oplus E_2}(\Phi^{-1} \circ (V_1 \oplus V_2) \circ \Phi)= \operatorname{tr}_{E_1}(V_1) \oplus \operatorname{tr}_{E_2}(V_2).
$$

Comment: domain of $(V_1 \oplus V_2)$ is $(E_1\otimes B)\oplus(E_2 \otimes B)$. Therefore shouldn`t be $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ be swaped?

Comment: @grigoriistepanov Yes, that was a silly mistake. See the latest edit.